# Bundle a angular 1.5.x application that was not built with npm

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs, bundle, minify

So I have this Angular app that I built, without thinking that it would grow so big and so fast.

**But now I have ~1.9MB being downloaded in 26 css files and 55 javascript files!!!**

Of course the loading time is terrible, taking over **20 seconds** to load!!!

[image]

Searching around, I found that I can bundle all the files into one `.html` file, 
one `.css` file, and one `.js` file. Using one of the many options available, webpack, rollup, gulp, grunt, and maybe a few others I missed.

The problem is, that I didn't use `npm` in the first place to install all the dependencies, rather downloaded the `min.js` file of each library, and included them all in the `index.html` file.

- Do I have any other choice other than essentially rebuilding my app with npm?
- Is there a simple guide that I can follow that will concat and minify all the  files so that I can see if it is really worth the hassle?
- And what is the simplest option of all the different bundling options available?

Comment: Mmmm, i think a quick fix for you would be to use VS' bundler and minifier extension(If you have VS available). No npm needed. Here's the link: https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier

Comment: @PrinayPanday Is there a similiar extension for vscode?

Comment: Sorry buddy, none that I know off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have another choice!

[Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) is your friend, is super easy to setup, and he will help you to bundle and compress all your js code to single or two files (i am splitting my bundled codecode to 2 files, one is all the lib files, including angular itself, and one file to my own code).

You can start with this simple article:
https://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/